# MS Project VBA - Return collection of tasks assigned to a summary task

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am looking for some VBA that will return a collection of tasks assigned to a sub task in Microsoft Project. I can use the .Summary method to identify a summary task, but how can I retrieve the tasks underneath that summary task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OutlineChildren` will give you the collection of immediate subtasks. For example, this code will loop through all tasks in the active project and print out the name of each summary task with the name of its subtask(s).

```
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    For Each s In t.OutlineChildren
        Debug.Print "Summary task: " & t.Name, "Subtask: " & s.Name
    Next s
Next t
```